# Will server's memory waste if we create a DialogBox then Hide it, then create & hide it many times (GWT)?

Tags: gwt

As you know there is no Close method in DialogBox. Look at this code:

```
myButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {DialogBox myD=new DialogBox(); } );
```

There's a hide button in DialogBox myD, so when users click Hide, the system will call `myD.hide();`

Look at this action:

```
User clicks myButton, then myD popup, then the user clicks Hide button to hide myD
```

Will server's memory waste if the user does the above action many times?

Will it create a lot of garbage in the server's memory? if it will, then how to code DialogBox properly?

Comment: The answer is no, it will not.
How should the server's memory usage change if a user creates a dialogbox on the client computer. Creating a dialogbox is a client-side action, that uses memory of the client computer. Once it is created, the dialogbox will be hidden if not needed instead of closed for performance reasons. A dialogbox will only use server memory, if it makes a call to the server.

Comment: will it waste memory on clients' PC?

Comment: yes, but that should not be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

The GUI of your GWT projects is running on each client. GWT transforms your Java (client) code into HTML, JavaScript and CSS . These are all client based techniques. So the server memory usage is not affected by your GUI, if you do not call any logic on the server.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the browser memory, not the server one.

Try declaring DialogBox myD; in your class and reusing the same instance. The hide() method javadoc says:

```
public void hide()
Description copied from class: PopupPanel
Hides the popup and detaches it from the page. This has no effect if it is not currently showing.
```

But widget creation is time and resource consuming. You can keep it if the popup is not used a lot (always the same equation: either more development and better programs, or less development and more resource consuming program)